# Chart.options returns "Property 'options' does not exist on type 'chart'"

Tags: html, angular, chart.js

I need to be able to edit the options of my chart after it is created. To do that I am running chart.options.[...] however this throws an error "Property 'options' does not exist on type 'Chart'" However not only does 'options' exist on type 'Chart' if I run the code it works fine and can change the options without issue.

So the error doesn't stop me from changing the options while 'ng serve' is already running however if I end that and try to recompile it will fail with the aforementioned error.

To buld the code:

```
this.LQChart = new Chart(this.myChart, {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: {
        labels:['Jobs']
    }, options: {
        plugins:{
            colorschemes: {
                scheme: 'brewer.YlOrBr9'
            },
            zoom:{
                pan: {
                    enabled: true,
                    mode: 'xy',
                    rangeMin: {
                        x: null,
                        y: null
                    },
                    rangeMax:{
                        x: null,
                        y: null
                    }
                },
                zoom:{
                    enabled: true,
                    drag: false,
                    mode:'xy',
                    rangeMin: {
                        x: null,
                        y: null
                    },
                    rangeMax:{
                        x: null,
                        y: null
                    },
                    speed:0.1
                }
            }
        }, legend: {
            display: false
        }, title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Location Quotient of Jobs in Region'
        }, scales: {
            yAxes: [{ 
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "# of Jobs"
                },
                id:'y-axis-0',
                type:'linear',
                gridLines: {
                    display:true
                },
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return Number(value.toString());
                     }
                 },
                     position:'left'
             }],
             xAxes: [{
                 scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     labelString: "LQ"
                 },
                 id: 'x-axis-0',
                 type: 'linear',
                 position: 'bottom',
             }]
         }, annotation: {
             annotations: [{
                 borderColor: 'black',
                 borderWidth: 2,
                 mode: 'vertical',
                 type: 'line',
                 value: 1.0,
                 scaleID: 'x-axis-0'
             }]
         }
     }
 });
```

To Change the options:

```
this.LQChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].type = 'logarithmic';
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working.
I do not know exactly what was causing this error however by treating the properties as array elements I was able to get it working perfectly fine.

```
this.LQChart['options']['scales']['yAxes'][0]['type'] = 'logarithmic';
```